# Loop through cells in a range, check for a condition and save results on a different s/s

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a loop which would go through each cell in a row and each row in a range, check if the value in each cell is "apple" and it it is, copy the date the cell was checked for and save the date in a separate sheet next to the id for which the check was done. I would appreciate help on this. Thank you. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVqr2.png)

[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVqr2.png)
[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bfm2.png)

Comment: please include your code and explain where stuck.

Comment: I don't know where to start with this one. It's something I have never done before -  I usually use VBA to just simply copy paste (no offsetting), apply filters, populate formulas.

Comment: I would read the range into an array and use index to slice out a column at a time and do application.match on the sliced column for search value Apple. If not iserror on the match take the first value in the column (the date) and write to other sheet. I think you want to search on a column basis given you have one value per column (is that correct?)

Comment: That still sounds too advanced for my skills. There can be more values in each column and I thought I would need to search on a row basis, one row per ID, but I guess searching on a column basis would give the same results. However, the dates should then be saved in adjacent sells on Sheet 2, in the same row as the ID, so, if there are two cells with "apple" for the same ID, say in columns D and L, the dates for those instances should be saved in the columns  C and D of Sheet2 and not in columns C and K and also the row would be different, as seen on the screenshots.

Comment: Ah.. so looping rows then columns is useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()

    Dim usedrows, usedcolumn, i, j As Integer

    usedrows = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    usedcolumn = ActiveSheet.Range("AZZ1").End(xlToLeft).Row

    For j = 4 To usedcolumn     'loop through columns
        For i = 4 To usedrows      'loop through rows
            If Cells(i, usedcolumn) = "Apple" Then

                Range("A" & i).Copy   'Copy the ID
                'paste it
                Cells(3, j).Copy ' Copy the date
                'paste it
            End If
            If Range("A" & i) = "" Then  'if end of the row loop next column
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
Next

End Sub
```